# tool for Tcl code , to check code formatting and for static code analysis system

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have been using `perltidy` and `Perl::Critic`  for checking Perl code before committing. Do we have any tool or module to the similar check for the TCL code?

Comment: Perl and Tcl are very different beasts. 1) Tcl's syntax is less free-form that Perl's, so there is less need for reformatting. 2) Perl has a wide variety of styles, practices, and historical artefacts that can easily cause subtle problems if mixed or misused: less so in plain old Tcl. 3) Tcl is more dynamic than Perl, making static analysis harder. 4) Tcl's user base is smaller and unfortunately less prone to create tools like these. There is a [style guide](http://www.tcl.tk/doc/styleGuide.pdf) and, as Donal wrote, Nagelfar (which isn't really up to date anymore, but still good).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual recommendation in this area is [Nagelfar](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nagelfar/), which is more up to date than most of the other alternatives. There may be other commercial options as well.

Answer (score 0):

[tclcheck](http://www.xdobry.de/), which is included in tclsqueak seems decent, is under development and the author is responsive to error reports.

Comment: Is it still under development, though? There hasn't been any updates for almost a year.

Comment: It worked pretty well when I tried it.  I have not had time to work with it and feed more issues to the author.   Either it works well enough for him, or he's stopped working on it.